# ¿Porque mi ventana en Java FX no abre?

Tags: java, javafx

Estoy realizando una interfaz (Estudiante) en la cual al abrirse deberia poder verse como a continuacion.

[image: VistaEstudiante]

Seguida de esta si se quiere modificar un estudiante abriria esta:

[image: EstudianteDialogVista]

-El problema esta en que al ejecutar el programa y darle al boton de abrir el panel de estudiantes me lanza esta serie de errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He revisado detenidamente mi codigo y quizas el error se encuentre en los controladores al tratar de manejar los arrayList con observableList de Java fx; "AdministracionEscolarController" simplemente contiene los metodos para abrir las ventanas desde la interfaz principal y el problema no creo que se encuentre ahi y mainApp tampoco porque ahi se encuentra la carga de los fxml de las views, si alguien me tendiera una mano lo agradeceria inmensamente!

Una parte de mi clase constructor es:

```
public class Colegio implements Serializable {

// Declaracion de Atributos privados (ArrayList respectivo de cada clase)

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private ArrayList<Profesor> listaProfesores;
private ArrayList<Materia> listaMaterias;
private ArrayList<Estudiante> listaEstudiantes;
private ArrayList<RegistroMaterias> listaRegistroMaterias;

/*
 * Constructor de lo que para nosotros es la clase principal, Desde esta clase
 * manejaremos la creacion respectiva de cada Profesor, materia,
 * estudiante y registros de materias que se realizen y seran alojados en un
 * arrayList respectivamente
 */
    Constructor clase Colegio
     public Colegio() {
    
    listaProfesores= new ArrayList<>();
    listaMaterias= new ArrayList<>();
    listaEstudiantes= new ArrayList<>();
    listaRegistroMaterias= new ArrayList<>();
}
```

El controlador de la ventana de estudiantes principal es:

```
public class CRUDEstudianteController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Button btnAgregar;
@FXML
private TableView<Estudiante> tblestudiantes;
@FXML
private TableColumn colCED;
@FXML
private TableColumn colNombre;
@FXML
private TableColumn colGrado;

@FXML
private ObservableList<Estudiante> estudiantes;
@FXML
private ObservableList<Estudiante> filtroEst;

@FXML
private Button btnModificar;
@FXML
private Button btnEliminar;
@FXML
private TextField txtFiltrarNombre;

@FXML private static MainApp cole;



public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    cole = AdministracionEscolarController.getCole();

    estudiantes = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    filtroEst = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    this.tblestudiantes.setItems(estudiantes);

    this.colNombre.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Nombre"));
    this.colCED.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("# Documento"));
    this.colGrado.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Grado"));



}

@FXML
private void agregarPersona(ActionEvent event) {

    try {

        // Cargo la vista
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("EstudianteDialogVista.fxml"));

        // Cargo la ventana
        Parent root = loader.load();

        // Cojo el controlador
        CRUDEstudianteDialog controlador = loader.getController();
        controlador.initAtributtes(estudiantes);

        // Creo el Scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.showAndWait();

        // cojo la persona devuelta
        Estudiante p = controlador.getEstudiante();
        if (p != null) {
            estudiantes.add(p);
            if (p.getNombreEstudiante().toLowerCase().contains(this.txtFiltrarNombre.getText().toLowerCase())) {
                this.filtroEst.add(p);
            }
            this.tblestudiantes.refresh();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setContentText(e.getMessage());
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

}


@FXML
private void modificar(ActionEvent event) {

    Estudiante p = this.tblestudiantes.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    if (p == null) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setContentText("Debes seleccionar un estudiante!");
        alert.showAndWait();
    } else {

        try {

            // Cargo la vista
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("EstudianteDialogVista.fxml"));

            // Cargo la ventana
            Parent root = loader.load();

            // Cojo el controlador
            CRUDEstudianteDialog controlador = loader.getController();
            controlador.initAtributtes(estudiantes,p);

            // Creo el Scene
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.showAndWait();

            // cojo la persona devuelta
            Estudiante pSeleccionado = controlador.getEstudiante();
            if (pSeleccionado != null) {
                if (!pSeleccionado.getNombreEstudiante().toLowerCase().contains(this.txtFiltrarNombre.getText().toLowerCase())) {
                    this.filtroEst.remove(pSeleccionado);
                }
                this.tblestudiantes.refresh();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setContentText(e.getMessage());
            alert.showAndWait();
        }

    }

}

@FXML
private void eliminar(ActionEvent event) {

    Estudiante p = this.tblestudiantes.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    if (p == null) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setContentText("Debes seleccionar un estudiante");
        alert.showAndWait();
    } else {
        // Elimino la persona
        this.estudiantes.remove(p);
        this.filtroEst.remove(p);
        this.tblestudiantes.refresh();

        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setTitle("Info");
        alert.setContentText("Estudiante eliminado");
        alert.showAndWait();

    }

}


@FXML
private void filtrarNombre(KeyEvent event) {

    String filtroNombre = this.txtFiltrarNombre.getText();

    // Si el texto del nombre esta vacio, seteamos la tabla de personas con el original
    if (filtroNombre.isEmpty()) {
        this.tblestudiantes.setItems(estudiantes);
    } else {

        // Limpio la lista
        this.filtroEst.clear();

        for (Estudiante p : this.estudiantes) {
            if (p.getNombreEstudiante().toLowerCase().contains(filtroNombre.toLowerCase())) {
                this.filtroEst.add(p);
            }
        }

        this.tblestudiantes.setItems(filtroEst);

    }

}
```

}

El codigo de controlador de la ventana por si se quiere modificar un estudiante es:

```
public class CRUDEstudianteDialog implements Initializable {


@FXML
private TextField tfce;

@FXML
private TextField tfne;
@FXML
private TextField txtEdad;
@FXML
private TextField txtApellidos;
@FXML
private TextField txtNombre;
@FXML
private Button btnGuardar;
@FXML
private Button btnSalir;
@FXML
private DatePicker dp;

@FXML
private ComboBox comboBox;

@FXML
private ComboBox comboBoxGradoEst;
@FXML private Label comboBoxgradosMateriasLabel;
@FXML
private Label DatePickerLabel;

private ObservableList<Estudiante> estudiantes;

private Estudiante estudiante;

@FXML private static MainApp cole;



@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

    cole = AdministracionEscolarController.getCole();
    estudiantes = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    //estudiantes = FXCollections.observableArrayList();



    comboBoxGradoEst.getItems().addAll( // Aqui aÃ±adimos los años
            // dados de la materia en el
            // comboBox
            "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11");

}



public void initAtributtes(ObservableList<Estudiante> estudiantes) {
    this.estudiantes = estudiantes;
}

public void initAtributtes(ObservableList<Estudiante> personas, Estudiante estudiante) {
    this.estudiantes = personas;
    this.estudiante = estudiante;
    // cargo los datos de la persona
    this.tfne.setText(this.estudiante.getNombreEstudiante());
    this.tfce.setText(this.estudiante.getIDEstudiante());
    this.comboBoxGradoEst.setAccessibleHelp((this.estudiante.getGrado()));
    this.dp.setPromptText(this.estudiante.getFechaNacimiento()+ "");
}

@FXML
private void salir(ActionEvent event) {
    this.estudiante = null;
    // Cerrar la ventana
    Stage stage = (Stage) this.btnGuardar.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
}



@FXML
private void agregarEstudiante(ActionEvent event) {


    String cedEstudiante, nomEstudiante, fNacimiento;
    String grado;

    boolean agregado;

    cedEstudiante = tfce.getText(); /*
                                     * Guardado de la cedula y nombre del
                                     * estudiante de los textFields
                                     */
    nomEstudiante = tfne.getText();

    fNacimiento = (String) (dp.getValue().toString()); // Guardado de la
                                                        // fecha de
                                                        // nacimiento segun
                                                        // la fecha del
                                                        // datePicker
    grado = (String)(comboBoxGradoEst.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());

    Estudiante est = cole.cole.agregarEstudiante(cedEstudiante, nomEstudiante, fNacimiento, grado); // Guardado
                                                                                                // de
                                                                                                // el
                                                                                                // estudiante
                                                                                                // en
                                                                                                // el
                                                                                                // mismo
                                                                                                // objeto
                                                                                                // del
                                                                                                // proyecto
                                                                                                // con
                                                                                                // sus
                                                                                                // respectivos
                                                                                                // atributos
                                                                                                // del
                                                                                                // constructor
                                                                                                // alojados
                                                                                                // en
                                                                                                // el colegio



    // Compruebo si la persona existe
    if (!estudiantes.contains(est)) {

        // Modificar
        if (this.estudiantes != null) {

            // Modifico el objeto
            this.estudiante.setIDEstudiante(cedEstudiante);
            this.estudiante.setNombreEstudiante(nomEstudiante);
            this.estudiante.setFechaNacimiento(fNacimiento);
            this.estudiante.setGrado(grado);


            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setTitle("Informacion");
            alert.setContentText("Se ha modificado correctamente");
            alert.showAndWait();

        } else {
            // insertando

            this.estudiante = est;
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setTitle("Informacion");
            alert.setContentText("Se ha añadido correctamente");
            alert.showAndWait();

        }

        // Cerrar la ventana
        Stage stage = (Stage) this.btnGuardar.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    } else {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setContentText("La persona ya existe");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }


}

public Estudiante getEstudiante() {
    return estudiante;
}




public void comboBoxSeleccionadoGradoPerteneceM() {

    this.comboBoxgradosMateriasLabel
            .setText("Grado Seleccionado: \n" + comboBoxGradoEst.getValue().toString());

}

public void datePickerSeleccionado() {

    this.DatePickerLabel.setText("Fecha: \n" + dp.getValue().toString());

}
```

El codigo de ventanaEstudiante.fxml :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="433.0" prefWidth="639.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="admin.colegial.view.CRUDEstudianteController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="btnAgregar" layoutX="60.0" layoutY="394.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#agregarPersona" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="149.0" text="Agregar Estudiante" />
      <TableView fx:id="tblPersonas" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="67.0" prefHeight="306.0" prefWidth="589.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="colNombre" prefWidth="215.0" text="Nombre" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="colApellidos" prefWidth="237.0" text="# Documento" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="colEdad" prefWidth="123.0" text="Grado" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <Button fx:id="btnModificar" layoutX="241.0" layoutY="394.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#modificar" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="169.0" text="Modificar Estudiante" />
      <Button fx:id="btnEliminar" layoutX="444.0" layoutY="394.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#eliminar" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="156.0" text="Eliminar Estudiante" />
      <Label layoutX="40.0" layoutY="29.0" text="Filtrar por nombre:" />
      <TextField fx:id="txtFiltrarNombre" layoutX="154.0" layoutY="25.0" onKeyReleased="#filtrarNombre" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Cuál es la línea 61 en `CRUDEstudianteController.java`?

Comment: Si puedes comparte el código del archivo `VentanaEstudiante.fxml`

Comment: Linea 61:  this.tblestudiantes.setItems(estudiantes);

Comment: Acabo de agregarlo a la publicacion, es muy extraño el error la verdad., llevo  buen rato analizando mi logica y demas cosas y aun no llego a la conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que, en el FXML de la vista, el identificador de la tabla es `tblPersonas` pero en el controllador (clase `CRUDEstudianteController`) el nombre del único atributo de tipo `TableView` es `tblestudiantes`. Ambos (id de la tabla en el FXML y el nombre del atributo correspondiente en el Controllador) tienen que coicidir para que JavaFX inyecte la referencia a la tabla en el atributo.

Como lo anterior no se cumple, al momento de llamar al método `initialize()` del controlador, el atributo `tblestudiantes` es `null` y al intentar manipularlo (haciendo esto: `this.tblestudiantes.setItems(estudiantes);`) se lanza un `NullPointerException`.

**Hay dos soluciones posibles:**

1. El nombre del atributo `tblestudiantes` lo cambias a `tblPersonas`, o
2. El identificador de la tabla en el archivo FXML lo cambias a `tblestudiantes`